# relations between ir_attachment and mail_messages in odoo 8

Tags: message, attachment, foreign-key-relationship, odoo-8

I tried to get relations between messages and ir attachment using psql, bu didn't find anything yet. i have message ids in mail_messages and attachment ids in ir_attachment. but i couldn't find which message has which attachment, like foreign key relation ship... any solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made my comments as below , kindly request you to find it as below it will  help in your case:

> What is the Relation Between `ir.attachment` and `mail.message`

Well `ir.attachment` and `mail.message` have [Many2many](http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#many2many) Realtion.

You can visualize it in ODOO [from here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/mail/models/mail_message.py#L53) and from  [ir.model](http://prntscr.com/asg81t)  in ODOO view  also.

For viewing this relation  records  look-up the table_name([message_attachment_rel](http://prntscr.com/asgkw5)) into pgadmin created by this relation or just connect with psql, type `\c your_db_name`  and `\dt` .

In side the column1 you will find the Ids for  `mail.message(message_id)` and in the column2 the Ids `ir.attachment(attachment_id)` .

I hope after visiting all these link your query will definitely solved.